# Read AND write ID3 tags to local files with javascript/jQuery via browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, id3

I haven't really found anything that can do just this - read AND write ID3 tags (to e.g. mp3 files). Should run from within a web browser.
Did anyone come by that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at https://github.com/interbred-monkey/id3_reader its a node module but its written purely in Javascript. I experienced some issues ready tags with it so I never tried writing with it but it mentions it supports this. Probably a good starting point for anyone looking to solve this problem.

Comment: If someone is still looking for this kind of library, you can look at my library, [mp3tag.js](https://github.com/eidoriantan/mp3tag.js). It can work in a browser and node and you can save the audio by downloading/saving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only read tags.See link below

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

Comment: Reading the related articles to that it seems to me it is possible, just nobody has done it yet (as DataView/jDataView have getters' as well as setters)?